# using rest and websockets in one application

Tags: java, websocket

Lets say i have an application that communicate with server using rest api.

Now i want to add chat to this application, and since i want it to be realtime  want to use websockets.

My question is, sincei will be using websockets, which already represent continuous connection, should drop rest and instead, all data that i want to recieve from server get through this web socket?

Also, what if i want to add another feature, different than chat that also needs to use websocets, should i implement another, second, websocket connection or shall i use the connection that i have already set up with first websockets (for chat)?

Thanks for help!.

Comment: No, you should drop REST communication.
Better to use WebSockets only for particular tasks.

Comment: for other "features", you can just use other topict to comunicate.